# Summarizing k-fold cross validation results

Tags: cross-validation

I have a project for which I had to do a 5-fold cross-validation. The dataset comprises of 5 days, so we take one day as our training set and apply on the remaining 4, rinse and repeat till we get full coverage. Pretty standard stuff.

Now, here's my question, once I finished the cross-validation, I am left with True Positive and False Positive rate for each one my runs.  Is there a standard way to show this data visually that would summarize the results ? In particular I want to show that the technique is fairly stable and about a day's worth of data is enough to train it successfully.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

box and whisker plots are commonly used to visually compare and summarize 
cross validation results.

[image]

Here is an example, taken from the [cvTools](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/cvTools/index.html) package in R.

```
library(cvTools)
## set up folds for cross-validation
folds <- cvFolds(nrow(coleman), K = 5, R = 50)
## compare LS, MM and LTS regression
# perform cross-validation for an LS regression model
fitLm <- lm(Y ~ ., data = coleman)
cvFitLm <- cvLm(fitLm, cost = rtmspe,
folds = folds, trim = 0.1)

...

# plot results for the MM regression model
bwplot(cvFitLmrob)
# plot combined results
bwplot(cvFits)
```

Comment: could you explain what the X and Y axis are ?

Comment: In this case, x represents the rms prediction errors over 5 repeated out of sample folds, across 3 different models. The corresponding model labels are represented on the y axis.

Comment: silly follow-on question, but do the parameters change for a logistic regression? e.g. would the code for logit just be: `fitLm <- glm(Y ~ ., data = coleman, family = 'binomial'); cvFitLm <- cvLm(fitLm, cost = rtmspe,folds = folds, trim = 0.1)`

Comment: This is a great solution, the only change I would make would be that since it appears that the user only has 5 fixed folds of cross-validation rather than the 5x50 repeated folds as specified by the answer, it might be better to plot the errors as points rather than as a boxplot.  Boxplots can be misleading for small numbers of data points, so it is often more informative to view independent instances until there get to be so many that the points become indistinguishable.