# Cross Validation CvTools package cvfolds error

Tags: r, logistic, cross-validation, goodness-of-fit

I am a beginner of Cross Validation tool, I would know what is the difference between CV and K-fold Cv.
The Second one, I don't understand why my R code doesn't work:

buddy <- cvFolds(nrow(buddy), K = 5, R = 10)
fit_buddy50 <- glm(default ~ ETA + Stipendio, data = buddy, family = 'binomial', alpha = 0.5)

The fit_buddy50 doesn't run and an error message comes up: 
Error in as.data.frame.default(data) : 
  cannot coerce class ""cvFolds"" to a data.frame
Thanks in advance

Comment: Please add a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/1217536) for people to work with.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about how to use R without a reproducible example.

Comment: Sorry, I am new in this group and I don't know very well how it works. Anyway, I have a dataset of 10700 observations. The analysis is about credit risk scoring, so the data have to validate some analysis about young people and their probability of eligibility for personal loans.

Comment: I follow the same example that you provided. Issues: error comes up " error in as.data.frame.default(data) : cannot coerce class 'cvfolds' to a data.frame. My data set contains 10700 numeric obs

Comment: Your programming question might be better on R-help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cross Validation is about the general technique of subsetting a data in complementary pieces, make an analysis (e.g. training a model) on selected subsets and them validate the analysis on the remaining. You can find more in [this paper](https://www.cs.utah.edu/~piyush/teaching/cross-validation-kohavi.pdf).

k-Fold Cross Validation is a type of Cross Validation technique where you split the data in k subsets of equal size and let one out of the analysis in each iteration, then you aggregate the results of the k iterations.

Other types are Leave-p-out Cross Validation and n-Fold Cross Validation.

About your code, you are overwriting your data with the folds, you have to run the model on the data. [This answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/41773/summarizing-k-fold-cross-validation-results) is explaining with an example.